# Cant make inline-flex column take 100% height of screen

Tags: css, flexbox

I cant seem to give my parent div a 100% height due to the fact that the React app div is not extending.

i have 3 children to the main Div which is class named as `side-bar-container`. I want the middle child to flex grow and take up all space and i did provide it a flex grow of 1 and others of 0 but the problem is there is no room to grow as shown in the picture.

edit: sorry i edited the question no react code is present im just trying to explain my issue

[image]

Comment: Do you mean 100% of the screen height? In this case, you'd want `100vh` on your parent container.

Comment: The sidebar will only take up as much space as it needs to without being told otherwise. If you put `height: 100vh` in the class ruleset, it will expand to the full height of the screen and give room for things to grow.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr yes it was this thank you for helping post as an answer pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to utilize the entire screen height on your parent container. You have 2 options:

1. Apply `100vh` on the `App` class, and then ensure your `side-bar-container` spans `100%` height.

```css
.App {
    height: 100vh;
}

.side-bar-container {
    height: 100%;
}
```

2. Apply `100vh` on `side-bar-container`.

```css
.side-bar-container {
    height: 100vh;
}
```